# Convert my java code to python: I don't understand why the values are different

Tags: python, java, while-loop

I have a problem with converting Java code to Python. Here is my code, it works and outputs the desired results:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
int i; // step number
int N =438; // the number of time steps
double t; // the time when all the drops evaporate;
double tmin=0; // the initial moment of time
double dt1=47.25; // the step by time for the value of nopt1
double dt2=10.22; // // the step by time for the value of nopt2
double a1, a2; // intermediate values for the final formula
double s1, s2; // intermediate values for the final formula
double y; // intermediate values for the final formula
double Dp; // coefficient of molecular diffusion of water vapor in air,m^2/s
double El; pressure of saturated water vapor over ice at temperature T, Pa
double Ev; // pressure of saturated water vapor with water at temperature T, Pa
double E0=610.78; // saturation pressure of water vapor at temperature T0 = 273.15, Pa
double S=1; // relative humidity
double rl; // radius of ice particles, m
double r1, r2; // radius of ice particles 
double r0l=2e-6; // initial radius of an ice particle, m
double r0v=4e-6; // initial radius of a drop,m
double t1,t2; // the time when all drops evaporate for nopt1 and nopt2;
double RR1, RR2; // intermediate values for the final formula
double rv1, rv2; //radius of water droplets, m
double L1, L2; // range of visibility for nopt1 and nopt2, m
double nopt1=1.1e+3; //the concentration of ice crystals 
double nopt2=1.1e+4; // concentration of ice crystals 
double T=268.15; // air temperature, K
double b=0.62; // dimensionless coefficient
double nv=1e+9; // volume concentration of a drop, m-3
double pl=917; // ice density, kg/m3
double pv=1000; // water density, kg/m3
double Rp=461; // gas constant of water vapor,
double P=100000;  // pressure, Pa

 PrintStream out1 = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("outfile1.txt"));
 PrintStream out2 = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("outfile2.txt"));
// The calculation is performed for two values of popt
// calculate the pressure of saturated water vapor above water and above ice at a temperature of T according to Magnus formulas
 Ev=E0*pow(10, ((7.63*(T-273.15))/(T-31.25)));
 El=E0*pow(10, ((9.5*(T-273.15))/(T-7.65)));
// calculate the coefficient of molecular diffusion of water vapor in the air
 Dp=(-1.89725e-5+1.5e-7*T)*(101326/P);
// Calculating part of the formula r1 and r2
 a1=pow(r0v,3)*((pv*nv)/(pl*nopt1))+pow(r0l,3);
 a2=pow(r0v,3)*((pv*nv)/(pl*nopt2))+pow(r0l,3);
// calculate the radius of ice particles corresponding to the moment of complete evaporation of droplets for nopt1 and nopt2
 r1=pow(a1, 1.0/3.0);
 r2=pow(a2, 1.0/3.0);
// Calculating part of the formula t1 and t2
 s1=(pow(r1,2)-pow(r0l,2))*pl*Rp*T;
 s2=(pow(r2,2)-pow(r0l,2))*pl*Rp*T;
// Calculating part of the formula t1 and t2
 y=2*Dp*Ev*(1-(El/Ev));
// Calculating the time when all drops will evaporate for nopt1 and nopt2
 t1=s1/y;
 t2=s2/y;
// Sequentially iterate over the values of "i" from 0 to t1
 for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
// Calculate the value of the time when all the drops evaporate by the value "i"
 t=tmin+dt1*i;

// Calculate the radius of the ice particles for the time interval from 0 to t1
 rl=pow(((r0l*r0l)+((2*Dp*Ev)/(pl*Rp*T))*(S-(El/Ev))*t),0.5);
// Calculating part of the rv1 formula
 RR1=(pow(r0v,3)*pv*nv+pl*nopt1*(pow(r0l,3)-pow(rl,3)))/(pv*nv);
// Calculate the radius of water droplets for the same time interval
 rv1=pow(RR1, 1.0/3.0);
// Calculating the range of visibility for the same time points
 L1=b/(nv*pow(rv1,2)+nopt1*pow(rl,2));

 System.out.printf(Locale.US, "%.2e\t%.2e\t%.2f\t%.2f\r\n", rv1, rl, t, L1);

 out1.printf(Locale.US, "%.2e\t%.2e\t%.2f\t%.2f\r\n", rv1, rl, t, L1);
}

// System out.printf(“n_opt2\r\n”);

// Sequentially iterate over the values of "i" from 0 to t2
 for(i=0;i<N;i++) {

 t=tmin+dt2*i;

 rl=pow(((r0l*r0l)+((2*Dp*Ev)/(pl*Rp*T))*(S-(El/Ev))*t),0.5);

 RR2=(pow(r0v,3)*pv*nv+pl*nopt2*(pow(r0l,3)-pow(rl,3)))/(pv*nv);

 rv2=pow(RR2, 1.0/3.0);

 L2=b/(nv*pow(rv2,2)+nopt2*pow(rl,2));

 System.out.printf(Locale.US, "%.2e\t%.2e\t%.2f\t%.2f\r\n", rv2, rl, t, L2);

 out2.printf(Locale.US, "%.2e\t%.2e\t%.2f\t%.2f\r\n", rv2, rl, t, L2);
}

 out1.close();
 out2.close();
}
}
```

Example of the result of the first column of rv2 (Java):
[the result of the first column of rv2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWVJc.png)

In short, my Python code considers the wrong step. I tried the for in i loop, moving the value of step i, but with little success.
I tried to rewrite this code in Python (output of the result to the terminal without saving):

```py
import math
N = 438
tmin = 0
dt1 = 47.25
dt2 = 10.22
E0 = 610.78  
S = 1
r0l = 2e-6
r0v = 4e-6
nopt1 = 1.1e+3
nopt2 = 1.1e+4
T = 268.15 
b = 0.62
nv = 1e+9
pl = 917
pv = 1000
Rp = 461
P = 1000000
pi = 3.14

i = 0

Ev = 610.78*pow(10, ((7.63*(T-273.15))/(T-31.25)))
El = 610.78*pow(10, ((9.5*(T-273.15))/(T-7.65)))
Dp = (-1.89725e-5+1.5e-7*T)*(101326/P)
a1 = pow(r0v, 3)*((pv*nv)/(pl*nopt1))+pow(r0l, 3)
a2 = pow(r0v, 3)*((pv*nv)/(pl*nopt2))+pow(r0l, 3)
r1 = pow(a1, 1.0/3.0)
r2 = pow(a2, 1.0/3.0)
s1 = (pow(r1, 2)-pow(r0l, 2))*pl*Rp*T
s2 = (pow(r2, 2)-pow(r0l, 2))*pl*Rp*T
y = 2*Dp*Ev*(1-(El/Ev))
t1 = s1/y
t2 = s2/y
# Sequentially iterate over the values of "i" from 0 to t2
while i < N:

    i += 1
    t = tmin+dt1*i
    rl = pow(((r0l*r0l)+((2*Dp*Ev)/(pl*Rp*T))*(S-(El/Ev))*t), 0.5)
    RR1 = (pow(r0v, 3)*pv*nv+pl*nopt1*(pow(r0l, 3)-pow(rl, 3)))/(pv*nv)
    rv1 = pow(RR1, 1.0/3.0)
    L1 = b/(nv*pow(rv1, 2)+nopt1*pow(rl, 2))
    print(rv1, rl, t, L1)

# Sequentially iterate over the values of "i" from 0 to t2
while i < N:
    i += 1
    t = tmin+dt2*i
    rl2 = pow(((r0l*r0l)+((2*Dp*Ev)/(pl*Rp*T))*(S-(El/Ev))*t), 0.5)
    RR2 = (pow(r0v, 3)*pv*nv+pl*nopt2*(pow(r0l, 3)-pow(rl, 3)))/(pv*nv)
    rv2 = pow(RR2, 1.0/3.0)
    L2 = b/(nv*pow(rv2, 2)+nopt2*pow(rl, 2))
    print(rv2, rl2, t, L2)
```

I think I have a problem with While Loops, the result is output with the wrong step (?) and the values do not change much.
Here is an example of the result of the first column of rv2 (Python):
[the result of the first column of rv2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxl4J.png)
The results in java and python are different.

Comment: Could you please specify what the code is doing and what your problem exactly is? You said you think you have a problem with the while loops, why? What aren't they doing? Please modify the question so it's more clear.

Comment: Initial value of `i` in the second while is not `0`, but last value of `i` at the end of previous loop. Also, I think in Java code while loops start with `i=0`, while in python code first loop starts with `i=1`  Also why use `while` loop and not for loop; `for i in range(N)`

Comment: See [mcve] please. Dont just write "I have a problem", tell us what you expect to happen and what happens instead. Also note: readability matters. Your java code is 10x harder to read than necessary. You write code that humans can read it, always remember that.

Comment: I've fixed everything about your python code, but the question is closed now XD. It had 3 issues. Please ping me here when it's opened. The full answer is ready.

Comment: @eternal_white I edited my question, I don't know if it will be reopened, but it seems that I just got everything right with the result! I changed the `While Loop` to `for in` and removed step `i` from the conditions before the loops. But thanks anyway for responding!

Comment: @Dova the 3 issues were the `i` variable not resetting to 0. And it was that you were using `rl` in the second loop instead of `rl2` (2 lines btw), and the third issue was that `P` constant was `10^6`, while in Java, it was `10^5` . Please fix them and let me know. If they're not working out with you, I can tell you exactly which lines, but try first.

Comment: @eternal_white yes, my bad, I fixed it and now everything works as it should! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could you try setting again i=0 before the second while loop?
In Python, local variables are scopped to the function, and not to the loop, so the i begins the second loop with i=N

Moreover, you should move your "i += 1" at the end of the loop.